# How to install clang-15 or higher? (16 preferably)

Tags: 22.04, compiling, cmake, clang

I am currently trying to build a project using cmake, and the error that occurs reads:

```
CMake Error at cmake/tools.cmake:33 (message):
  Compilation with Clang version 14.0.0 is unsupported, the minimum required
  version is 15.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:18 (include)
```

every time I `apt get` clang, it by default installs a 14 version. How do I fix this?

This is a little urgent, so any help is appreciated. Thanks! :)

Comment: I see *clang* 15 & 16 available for some releases, but you've not told us what you're running, are you hoping we guess?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software)

Comment: My ubuntu version is 22.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

clang has been updated in Ubuntu 22.04, so that it is possible to install clang-15 in Ubuntu 22.04 with the following commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install clang-15
```

The development version of 23.10 has clang 16 in the mantic-proposed/universe software source if you prefer that.